# Rails how to differentiate two columns in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My association are described below:

Konkurrancers belongs to Kategori

Kategori has many Konkurrancers.

In my konkurrancers table i have:

```
rating_score
ratings
class KategorisController < ApplicationController
  def show
  @kategori = Kategori.where(:cached_slug => params[:id]).first
// Does not work
   @rating = @kategori.konkurrancers.rating_score / @kategori.konkurrancers.ratings
  end
end
```

I get this error in view:

```
NoMethodError in KategorisController#show

undefined method `rating_score' for #<Class:0x5f3e590>
```

The column ratings holds the number of ratings
and the rating_score holds the rating

And I want to differentiate those two columns as following: rating_score/ratings

How do I create this in my controller?

Comment: Where you say it *does not work*, what happens?

Comment: I have updated my Qustion with further information

Comment: Can you add your view code also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `kategori` has multiple `konkurrancers` so konkurrancers is an array. You need to define of which konkurrancers you take the rating_score

You should try:

```
@kategori.konkurrancers[0].rating_score
```

Above code will only work if you have at least 1 `@kategori.konkurrancers` ofcourse

**UPDATE**

```
@rating = 0
@kategori.konkurrancers.each do |k|
    @rating += k.rating_score
end

@rating /=  @kategori.konkurrancers.count
```

Comment: Then i can pass my @rating in my konkurrancers loop

Comment: I assume you will have multiple rating for a kategori?

Comment: The rating is in the column of konkurrancers table

Comment: indeed, but since kategori has multiple konkurrancers, you will have multiple ratings per kategori.

Comment: Ratings is a column in konkurrancers table

Comment: It does not work. I need to say example: ratings are 5 rating_score is 24. Rating for konkurrance is rating_score/ratings=24/5=4,5